# Are $[0,1)\times\Bbb R$ and $[0,1)\times\Bbb Q$ similar?

Tags: order-theory

> Let $a:=[0,1)\times\Bbb R$ and $b:=[0,1)\times\Bbb Q$ and let $\prec_a$ and $\prec_b$ denote their respective antilexicographic orders. Are $(a,\prec_a)$ and $(b,\prec_b)$ similar?

> $\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{definition 1}:}}$ Partially ordered sets $(a,\prec_a)$ and $(b,\prec_b)$ are said to be similar if there is an order-preserving bijection $f:a\to b$ with an order-preserving inverse $f^{-1}.$

> $\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{definition 2 }:}}$ Subset $b$ of a partially ordered set $a$ is said to be convex if, for any $x,y\in b$ and $z\in a,$ $$x<z<y\implies z\in b.$$

> $\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{definition 3 }:}}$ Partially ordered set $(a,<)$ is set to be complete if every subset of $a$ bounded from above has a least upper bound in $a$.

> $\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{definition 4 }:}}$ Let $(a,\prec_a)$ and $(b,\prec_b)$ be two partially ordered sets. We define the antilexicographic order on the product $a\times b$ as
>
> $(x_1,y_1)<(x_2,y_2):\iff y_1\prec_b y_2\text{ or } (y_1=y_2\text{ and } x_1\prec_a x_2)$

Convexity and completeness are properties invariant under a similarity so, a complete convex subset of $[0,1)\times\Bbb R$ should be mapped to a complete convex subset of $[0,1)\times\Bbb Q.$ I believe the only such subsets in both of $a$ and $b$ are segments $[(x,z),(y,z)]$ for $x,y\in[0,1), x\le y$ and $z\in\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Q$ because the segments go zig-zag, yet, for example $[0,1)\times\{0\},$ which is bounded from above, doesn't have a supremum in either of the sets as we can choose an arbitrarily small $x>0$ so that $(0,x)$ is an upper bound for $[0,1)\times\{0\}.$

However, since $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, I couldn't figure out how to obtain a countable partition of $a$ into such subsets that would map to suitable subsets in $b$ and it seems in $b$ such partitions would be countable, but I wasn't able to write my thoughts down any further.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please define "antilexicogrphic". I *might* be able to guess what that means, but at risk of getting it backwards I wouldn't want to answer the question.

Comment: Why not consider $\Bbb R \times [0,1)$ and $\Bbb Q \times [0,1)$ with lexicographic order? It seems to me that by reversing the product order and then considering antilexicographic order you're inviting careless mistakes to be made. Regarding your question, note that between any two different right coordinates (left coordinates my way) there are uncountably many copies of $[0,1)$ for the 1st ordered set and only countably many copies of $[0,1)$ for the 2nd ordered set.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, the antilexicographic order was in the original text so I tried to solve it. For your last statement, I tried to incorporate it into my attempt in the end of the post. I probably haven't put that into words very well.

Comment: If you're comfortable with antilexicographic order, fine. If not, then reverse the product order, work with lexicographic order, then translate back when you have what you need. My "regarding your question" observation is intended to show that it's obvious they are not order isomorphic. How formal you need to dress up that observation will, of course, depend on the text/course/teacher.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Isn't it traditional to define the product $\alpha\beta$ of two order types as the antilexicographic order on $A\times B$? Isn't this question just asking whether $(1+\lambda)\lambda=(1+\eta)\lambda$ where $\eta$ is the order type of the rational numbers and $\lambda$ the order type of the real numbers? And isn't it answered by simply noting that only one of them has a countable dense subset?

Comment: Seems to me that $[0,1)\times\mathbb Q$ has a countable dense subset while $[0,1)\times\mathbb R$ does not. Is that right, and doesn't that do the trick? Is "similar" the same as "isomorphic"?

Comment: @bof, I was thinking about that after reading your comment. So, on every "level" there shold be a member of a dense set, right? Could you make your comment an aswer? Separability is indeed invariant if I got the term right.

Comment: @bof, your observation would do the trick. I was all in the topological definition of density that I missed it.

Comment: Sorry but I'm too sleepy. Would you mind writing a self-answer?

Comment: @bof, no problem! Sweet dreams!

Comment: @bof: You're right, and I'd forgotten about this convention for products of order types (that I dislike -- when discussing "small" countable ordinals, e.g. $\omega + \omega,$ do I use the correct $\omega 2$ and risk my intended audience getting confused at why I didn't write $2\omega),$ or at least I submerged it, despite having spent several months in 1985 with a fairly thorough self-study of linearly/totally ordered sets (and 60 some pages of carefully made handwritten notes). However, seeing your use of the standard symbols for reals and rationals reminded me of it, with a silent "oops".

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro The alternative to the notation you dislike would be to have $$\omega^{\alpha+\beta}=\omega^\beta\omega^\alpha$$ unless you also want to write addition backwards so that the successor of $\omega$ is $1+\omega$.

Comment: Oops, bad typo in my first comment. Instead of $(1+\lambda)\lambda=(1+\eta)\lambda$ I meant to write $(1+\lambda)\lambda=(1+\lambda)\eta$.

Comment: @bof: *The alternative to the notation you dislike ...* --- And here we have another arithmetical fact about linear order arithmetic that I've forgotten $\ldots$ For what it's worth, my main (but not only) references for linear orders during my 1985 study of them (references of possible interest to Invisible) are listed in my comment to [https://mathoverflow.net/q/402320/15780](https://mathoverflow.net/q/402320/15780).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, thank you for the thread!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer in the follow up to Bof's comment

---

> $\underline{\boldsymbol{\text{definition }:}}$ Suppose $(a,\prec)$ is a totally ordered set and $b\subseteq a.$ $b$ is said to be dense in $a$ if for all $(x,y)\in\prec,$ there is some $z\in b$ such that $x\prec z\prec y.$

Let's consider $(x_1,y), (x_2,y)\in [0,1)\times\Bbb R=a.$

If $c\subseteq a$ is dense in $a,$ then there is $(z_1,z_2)\in c$ such that $(x_1,y)\prec_a(z_1,z_2)\prec_a(x_2,y).\space \implies$
$x_1<z_1<x_2$ and $z_2=y.$

As Dave L. Renfro pointed out, there are uncountably many copies of $[0,1)$ in $a,$ therefore, a $c$ dense in $a$ is necessarily uncountable. Hence $a$ doesn't have a countable subset dense in it.

On the other hand, $b$ has, for example $[0,1)\times\Bbb Q\cap\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q.$

Existence of a subset dense in a set is a property invariant under a similarity, so $a$ and $b$ cannot be similar.